# jQuery IE6 hover script not working

Tags: jquery, png, hover, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-6

I have spent hours and I cannot for the life of me figure out why the jQuery IE6 hover fix (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ie6hover) is not working. Also, perhaps unrelated, but I can't seem to get http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/ or for that matter ANY IE6 hacks working for my Shopify site. Any advice would be treasured. Here are the relevant sections of my code that's output (after Shopify does its thing):

```
<head>

<link href="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0070/7142/t/1/assets/stylesheet.css?122494" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all"  />
<script src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0070/7142/t/1/assets/jquery-1.5.2.min.js?122494" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--[if IE 6]>
<script src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0070/7142/t/1/assets/DD_belatedPNG.js?122494" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    DD_belatedPNG.fix('.pngy');
</script>

<script src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0070/7142/t/1/assets/jquery.ie6hover.js?122494" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ie6hover(true);
</script>
<![endif]-->

</head

<body>

<a href="/"><img class="pngy" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0070/7142/t/1/assets/alternative-radio-logo.png?122494" width="379" height="80" /></a>

<ul>
  <li >
    <a href="/collections/all-programs" class="strong-link">Programs</a>
    <ul class="sub-navigation">
      <li><a href="/collections/latest-programs">Latest Programs</a></li>
      <li><a href="/collections/staff-favorites">Staff Favorites</a></li>
      <li><a href="/collections/subscriptions">Season Subscriptions</a></li>
      <li><a href="/collections/all-programs">All Programs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li >
    <a href="/pages/speakers" class="strong-link">Speakers</a>
  </li>
  <li >
    <a href="/pages/podcast" class="strong-link">Podcast</a>
  </li>
  <li >
    <a href="/pages/affiliates" class="strong-link">Stations</a>
    <ul class="sub-navigation">
      <li><a href="/pages/affiliates">Affiliate Stations</a></li>
      <li><a href="/blogs/news-for-affiliates">News for Affiliates</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li  >
    <a href="/pages/about-ar">About</a>
  </li>
  <li  >
    <a href="/blogs/news-updates">News Updates</a>
  </li>
  <li  >
    <a href="/pages/about-barsamian">Barsamian</a>
  </li>
  <li class="last" >
    <a href="/pages/contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
<div class="clear"></div>
</ul>

</body>
```

and here's the relevant CSS from stylesheet.css (I have taken out colors, font styling, padding, and shadows):

```
div#navigation ul {
    float: left;
    z-index: 10;
}

div#navigation ul li {
    display: block;
    float:left;
}

li:hover ul, li.over ul { 
    display: block;
}

div#navigation ul li a {
    display:block;
}

div#navigation ul li ul.sub-navigation {
    display:none;
    width:180px;
}

div#navigation ul li:hover ul.sub-navigation {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}

div#navigation ul li:hover ul.sub-navigation li {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: there is an unclosed head tag..

Comment: Man, who's making you support IE6? Even Google dropped support. Still, I've always liked Dean Edwards IE*.js series of scripts. There's now IE9.js which adds everything missing from IE6-8 to those browsers. It might not fix your problem, but one script instead of many means less moving parts to debug.

Comment: @amosrivera I typed those in at the last second for viewing purposes--it's correct in my code. Thanks though.

Comment: @chrisdpratt Thank you for introducing me to IE9.js! It fixed the png problem, and what convenience. Unfortunately the hover issue remains :\

Comment: Are you using IE9.js for both now, or still trying to use the plugin for hover? With IE9.js, you don't have to do anything else special. You can just use the li:hover pseudo-class as you please.

Comment: With or without the hover fix plugin (and IE9.js installed), my :hover pseudo-classes still don't work. No clue why.

Answer (score 0):

For your hover issue,

I'm not sure if the jQuery plugin fixes this, but in IE6 you cannot put :hover on anything but an 'a' and you have it on an 'li'. If that's what the plugin fixes then my comment is useless.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's exactly what the plugin is for ;).